# recurring date functions in php

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

Good Day,

I am trying to create a recurring date system that has the following:

nth day of nth month (2nd day of every 3rd month)

```
$this_months_friday = strtotime('+3 days +4 months');
```

the output of that will always be current day + 3 days of the 4th month.

how do I get it to display the nth day of the nth month?

since i also tried

```
$this_months_friday = strtotime('every 3 days +4 months');
```

and it did not return any result. Should i stick with strtotime on this one or move to DateTime function of php. though i wont still be able to formulate the proper argument for that kind of date sequence.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably better off using DateTime with a couple intervals:

```
$d = new DateTime();
$d->add(new DateInterVal('P' . $days . 'D'))->add('new DateInterVal('P' . $months . 'M'));
```

not sure what youre two example intervals are wanting.

You want an internval to start in 4 months, which then repeats every 3 days?

That'd be something more like

```
$d = new DateTime();
$d->add(new DateInterval('P4M')); // jump ahead 4 months immediately
$day3 = new DateInterval('P3D');

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
   $d->add($day3); // jump ahead 3 days
   ... do something with this new date
}
```

for a basic recurring event, +4 months + 3 days, you'd simply have one interval:

```
$interval = new DateInteval('P4M3D'); // +4 months +3 days
$date = new DateTime();
while($some_condition) {
   $date->add($interval);
   do_something();
}
```

Comment: no its more like every 4th day of the 4th month, i did +3 days +4 months based on some reading where +3 meant that it would be on the 3rd day, and +4 months since it will always be recurring every 4 months.

Comment: no. strtotime will interpret `+3 days` as 3 days from now. same with +4 months. e.g. today +3 days +4 months would make it Nov 12th. you'll probably have to bite the bullet and do some date math. e.g. calculate +4 months (Nov), then rebuild a new date string `2013-$M-03` to get the 3rd. strtotime's english parsing is amazing sometimes, but it's **NOT** psychic. and ENTIRELY too fallible.

Comment: oh i see, how could i make it then to interpret it as a recurring event? actually i was thinking of resetting the value every time the date comes. but i was hoping to find a simpler function for this though

Comment: php doesn't do recurring events. that's up to you. see my last edit on the answer above.

Comment: i see, thank you but would you mind adding some explanation to your answer. thanks :)

Comment: the loop does the "recurring". it'll keep spitting out more dates,e ach being 4months3days farther ahead than the last time around the loop.

Comment: tried $date = new DateTime('NOW');
$interval = new DateInteval('P4M3D'); // +4 months +3 days
$date->add($interval);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n"; but didnt get any result

Comment: only works if i comment the interval part. weird. let me do some changes.

Comment: there was a type on DateInterval, it was missing an r. lol. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by saving the values in  variables like that :

```
    $day=3;
    $month=4;
    echo date("d-m-y",strtotime('+'.$day .'days' .'+'.$month.'months'));
```

Explanation:

**7**(july)+**4** months = **11** month(November)

**8** july+ **3** days = **11** july

Output:
11-11-13

**NOTE:** just for the example I have put the values hard coded, You can  make them dynamic.